# Set Office 365 Group calendar to only Admin to create Events

Tags: office-365, outlook, office-365-groups

I am looking for a way to allow only group admin to create events on Office 365 Outlook Group Calendar.

Answer (score 0):

You can redirect Members to read only on the calendar using the Exchange Management Shell cmdlets. This will require that you be an Owner of the Group to create/modify the calendar.

```
$group = Get-UnifiedGroup "My Group Name"
Set-UnifiedGroup -Identity $group.Id -CalendarMemberReadOnly
```

[Set-UnifiedGroup](https://docs.microsoft.com/powershell/module/exchange/set-unifiedgroup?view=exchange-ps)

Comment: Thank you, it worked